# how to stop the chart keys swapping places in ggplot2

Tags: r, charts, ggplot2

I several sets of similar data that I want to chart in a bubble chart where the size of the bubble is determined by one variable and the colour by another. I've been able to produce the chart exactly how I want it, however depending on which data set I select either the size key is on top of the colour key or vice versa. It doesn't really affect the charts at all, but when I'm presenting them it looks inconsistent, and I'd like them all to have the same overall appearance. The code looks something like this example version. If I run this as is with `d <- d1` the colour key is on top, if I change it so that `d <- d2` the size key is on top. Why is this happening and how can I make it stop?

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

d1 <- data.frame(
  da = c(0.00010306, 0.000107541, 0.000258532, 0.000476923, 0.00078378, 0.001052035, 0.00085944, 0.000870465, 0.000739446, 0.000408369, 0.000605991, 0.000530189, 0.000974861, 0.000934616, 0.000278138),
  db = c(0.000148792, 0.000131408, 0.000278016, 0.000551079, 0.000666495, 0.000831947, 0.000936617, 0.001082583, 0.000608943, 0.000396024, 0.000524359, 0.000437993, 0.002154684, 0.001587134, 0.000714796),
  dc = c(0.133521655, 0.144845498, 0.101336906, 0.088712025, 0.09323026, 0.110413413, 0.094363199, 0.10419398, 0.120285594,0.100113788, 0.149558696, 0.201749624, 0.182900523, 0.368043927, 0.129705173),
  dd = c(805360, 1050761, 1206816, 920484, 708107, 576977, 656241, 469864, 286701, 252223, 140266, 79217, 48212, 25679, 10786),
  de = c("17-20", "21-24", "25-29", "30-34", "35-39", "40-44", "45-49", "50-54", "55-59", "60-64", "65-69", "70-74", "75-79", "80-84", "85-200")
)

d2 <- data.frame(
  da = c(0.000131808, 0.000121259, 0.000165209, 0.00018363, 0.000198166, 0.000246498, 0.000313704, 0.000348308, 0.000382333, 0.000754634),
  db = c(0.000186259, 0.000110078, 0.000106929, 0.000146352, 0.000152172, 0.000198098, 0.000309055, 0.000395655, 0.000412634, 0.000766681),
  dc = c(0.117943325, 0.11863063, 0.118848522, 0.119496562, 0.124023717, 0.114608571, 0.106225196, 0.097814806, 0.098002309, 0.112509492),
  dd = c(682811, 536042, 393442, 343081, 317915, 308319, 274144, 284231, 272014, 3825695),
  de = c("0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9+")
)

d <- d1 # changing this to d <- d2 flips the legends' positioning

upperLimit <- 0.26
varPart <- "Variable part"

c <- ggplot(data = d, aes(x = d$da, y = d$db))

c + geom_point(aes(colour = d$dc, size = d$dd), alpha = 0.7) + 
  scale_colour_gradientn(colours=rainbow(4), name = paste(varPart,"dc name"), labels = percent, limits = c(0, upperLimit)) +
  scale_size_continuous(range = c(3, 15), name = paste(varPart, "dd name"), labels = comma) +
  geom_text(aes(label = d$de), size=3) +
  xlab("da name") + ylab("db name") + ggtitle("Product Conversion versus Other Product Conversion by Factors") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = percent) +
  scale_x_continuous(labels = percent) +
  geom_abline(intercept=0, slope=1) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = mean(d$db)) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = mean(d$da))
```

Comment: Can't reproduce the flip. The size key is always on top. I'm using the current RStudio version and R version 3.2.2.

Comment: Same..doesn't flip with `ggplot2 2.0.0`. Though I have to remove arg. references to `labels = percent` and `labels = comma` from the plot function  to avoid error.

Comment: I had ggplot2 version 1.0.0. I've installed version 2.0.0 and the problem has disappeared. Thanks